# listFiles() nullpointerexception when called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-2.0

I'm calling listFiles() with read and write permissions granted; on Android 11 but it gives a NullPointerException error even tho the path is correct (I got the path from a ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() Activity) and stored as variable like so `folderPath = it.path`

```
var mydir = File(folderPath)
files = mydir.listFiles()!!
```

it results in NullPointerException still even tho mydir is printed correctly, example:

`/tree/primary:SHAREit Lite/pictures`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got the path from a ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() Activity

Then you are not dealing with the filesystem. You are using the Storage Access Framework, which is an abstraction around a lot of different possible places for content to be stored. But this means that you need to stop using `File`, because the content may not be on the filesystem, and a `Uri` is not a filesystem path.

Instead, use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` on the tree identified by the `Uri` that you got from `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()`. You can call `listFiles()` on that to get `DocumentFile` objects representing the direct contents of that tree.